# GORM: Select fields from two tables while joining

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have `products` table which has one-to-many relationship with `items` and `brands` tables. `brands` also have one-to-many relationship with `items`.

I was trying to query products and group them based on `product_id` and `brand_id` and it seems to work fine.

The only problem I have right now is that I can't map these fields `brandId` and `BrandName`, They always nil. But querying the raw SQL statement it generates the desired result.

Here are my models. Some fields have been omitted for simplicity.

```golang
type Brand struct {
    ID          int        `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name        string     `json:"name" gorm:"index;not null;type:varchar(50);default:null"`
    ProductID   int        `json:"productId"`
    Product     *Product   `json:"product" gorm:"foreignKey:ProductID;"`
}

type Product struct {
    ID          int         `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name        string      `json:"name" gorm:"index;not null;type:varchar(50);default:null"`
    StoreID     *int        `json:"storeId"`
    Store       *Store      `json:"store" gorm:"foreignKey:StoreID;constraint:OnUpdate:RESTRICT,OnDelete:RESTRICT;"`
    BrandID     *int        `json:"brandId" gorm:"-"` //SEE THIS
    BrandName   *string     `json:"brandName" gorm:"-"` //SEE THIS TOO
    Brands      []*Brand    `json:"brands" gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:RESTRICT;"`
}

type Item struct {
    ID            int         `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Quantity      int         `json:"quantity" gorm:"type:integer;not null;unsigned;"`
    ProductID     int         `json:"productId"`
    Product       *Product    `json:"product" gorm:"foreignKey:ProductID;not null;constraint:OnUpdate:RESTRICT,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
    BrandID       *int        `json:"brandId"`
    Brand         *Brand      `json:"brand" gorm:"foreignKey:BrandID;constraint:OnUpdate:RESTRICT,OnDelete:CASCADE;"`
}



var products []*model.Product
var result *gorm.DB

query := DB.Table("products").
        Where(&model.Product{StoreID: &StoreID}).
        Joins("INNER JOIN items ON items.product_id = products.id").
        Joins("LEFT JOIN brands ON brands.id = items.brand_id").
        Where("items.quantity > 0").
        Group("products.id, brands.id").
        Select("products.*,brands.id AS brand_id, brands.name AS brand_name")

    if err := query.Find(&products).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    //Here results contains no brand_id nor brand_name
    fmt.Printf("result %+v\n", products)
```

Here is raw SQL generated by gorm. And work as expected outside gorm

```sql
SELECT products.*,brands.id AS brand_id, brands.name AS brand_name 
FROM "products" 
INNER JOIN items ON items.product_id = products.id 
LEFT JOIN brands ON brands.id = items.brand_id 
WHERE "products"."store_id" = 2 AND items.quantity > 0 
GROUP BY products.id, brands.id
```

First solution that comes in mind is to use `->` instead of `-` gorm tag.

Like this

```
    BrandID     : Int @goTag(key: "gorm", value: "->")
    BrandName   : String @goTag(key: "gorm", value: "->")
```

The only drawback with this is that it saves these fields on database.

Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

[has_many](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html)

```
type Brand struct {
    ID          int        `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name        string     `json:"name" gorm:"index;not null;type:varchar(50);default:null"`
    ProductID   int        `json:"productId"`
}

type Product struct {
    ID          int         `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name        string      `json:"name" gorm:"index;not null;type:varchar(50);default:null"`
    StoreID     *int        `json:"storeId"`
    Store       *Store      `json:"store" gorm:"foreignKey:StoreID;constraint:OnUpdate:RESTRICT,OnDelete:RESTRICT;"`
    Brands      []*Brand    `json:"brands" gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:RESTRICT;"`
}
```

you shouold read `BrandId` and `BrandName` in model-`Brand` but model-`Product`

Product have many Brands, so it have many BrandID/BrandName, why you defiene just **a** `BrandName`or `BrandID`?

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have updated some info can you re-read the question'